# Extract first two digits that comes after some string in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a row with values something like this, How to extract first two digits that come after the text 'ABCD' to another cell, any formula or vba? There may be a few chars in between or sometimes none.

- ABCD 10 sadkf sdfas
- ABCD-20sdf  asdf
- ABCD  40
- ABCD50 asdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a worksheet formula. No need for VBA.

Assuming you do not need to test for the presence of two digits:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")),2)
```

If you need to test for the presence of two digits, you can try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(-RIGHT(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")),2),1)),MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")),2),"Invalid")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is always a good idea to show some code in StackOverflow. Thus, you show that you have tried something and you give some directions for the answer.

Concerning the first two digits extract, there are many ways to do this. Starting from RegEx and finishing with a simple looping of the chars and checking each one of them.

This is the loop option:

```
Public Function ExtractTwoDigits(inputString As String) As Long

    Application.Volatile

    Dim cnt     As Long
    Dim curChar As String

    For cnt = 1 To Len(inputString)
        curChar = Mid(inputString, cnt, 1)
        If IsNumeric(curChar) Then
            If Len(ExtractTwoDigits) Then
                ExtractTwoDigits = ExtractTwoDigits & curChar
                Exit Function
            Else
                ExtractTwoDigits = curChar
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt

    ExtractTwoDigits = -1

End Function
```

- `Application.Volatile` makes sure that the formula recalculates every time;
- `-1` is the answer if no two digits exist in the `inputString`;
- `IsNumeric` checks whether the string inside is numeric;
- As a further step, you may try to make the function a bit robust, extracting the first `1`, `3`, `4` or `5` digits, depending on a parameter that you put. Something like this `=ExtractTwoDigits("tarato123ra2",4)`, returning `1232`.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx Version:

```
Public Function GetFirstTwoNumbers(ByVal strInput As String) As Integer
Dim reg As New RegExp, matches As MatchCollection

With reg
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\d{2})"
End With

Set matches = reg.Execute(strInput)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    GetFirstTwoNumbers = matches(0)
Else
    GetFirstTwoNumbers = -1
End If
End Function
```

You have to enable `Microsoft Regular Expressions 5.5` under extras->references. The pattern `(\d{2})` matches 2 digits, return value is the number, if not existing -1.

Note: it only extracts 2 successive numbers.

If you place this function into a module, you can use it like normal formula.

[Here](https://regexr.com/) a great site to to get into regEx.